# Powershell to Json file

Tags: json, powershell

i'm trying to get a list of all devices with yellow bang on a given platform, write it as a dictionary to json file, and finally read it via python script.

All seems pretty easy, i can save the string to json file but when i try to open it i get an error.
i can't figure out if the problem is with the powershell script, or maybe i'm just not constructing the json object correctly.

```
$baddevices = Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | where {$_.ConfigManagerErrorcode -ne 0}

$jsonRepresentation = '{'

foreach ($device in $baddevices) {
    $jsonRepresentation = $jsonRepresentation + " {0}: {1}," -f $device.name, $device.deviceid 
}


$jsonRepresentation = $jsonRepresentation.Substring(0,$jsonRepresentation.Length-1) + '}'


$jsonRepresentation | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "C:\file.json"
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what your trying to do in the middle there, I think its just not necessary.

Try:

```
$baddevices = Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | where {$_.ConfigManagerErrorcode -ne 0}

$baddevices| ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "C:\file.json"
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks that works great, was also able to get only the name and hardware it using $baddevices = Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | where {$_.ConfigManagerErrorcode -ne 0} | Select Name, DeviceID

Comment: Well the powershell script works, but now i get an error trying to load it in python "ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)". I've also noticed that powershell saved the data as a list with dictionaries instead of a single dictionarie with values.