# Serialize _wmi_object into JSON in Python3

Tags: python, json, object, serialization, wmi

I am having hard time with serializing `_wmi_objects`. I have tried with just `json.dumps()` and `JsonPickle` library without success getting `Not JSON serializable` errors or with `JsonPickle` some unneeded fields which can't be removed and null values for every entity.Tried hardcoding every entity in a dict literal and after that `json.dumps()` and it dumps only the first result. Also tried making the object into a `dict` which had the result below.

This is what I have until now:

```
import wmi, json


def to_dict(obj):
    output ={}
    for key, item in obj.__dict__.items():
        if isinstance(item, list):
            l = []
            for item in item:
                d = to_dict(item)
                l.append(d)
            output[key] = l
        else:
            output[key] = item

    return output


c = wmi.WMI(
    computer="host",
    user="user",
    password="password"
)

for product in c.Win32_Product():
     with open('products.json','w') as fp:
         fp.write(json.dumps(to_dict(product)))
```

With the code above I am getting `TypeError: Object of type CDispatch is not JSON serializable`

This the data that I'm getting when I `print(product)`:

```
instance of Win32_Product
{
        AssignmentType = 1;
        Caption = "Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 X64 Additional Runtime - 14.22.27821";
        Description = "Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 X64 Additional Runtime - 14.22.27821";
};
```

Comment: Do your have the ability for [handling-stateful-objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#handling-stateful-objects)?

Comment: Nope, `TypeError: Can't pickle PyIDispatch objects`

Comment: You have to change in your `def to_dict(` to [what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)

Comment: I'm not sure if I am understanding correctly, but I tried to add the `return pickle.dumps(output)` in the `def to_dict()`.And it gave `Object of Type _wmi_object is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Add a `print(type(item))` beneath `for key, item in ...` and compare the output with the table in [what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)

Comment: it returns `<class 'wmi._wmi_object'>` so it should be pickled, but still not being able to serialize...

Comment: Did you find type `<class 'wmi._wmi_object'>` in the list in [what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)? The answer is: **No**, therefor can't be pickled.

Comment: Microsoft already provides functionality to output WMI results to JSON using Powershell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183554/powershell-to-json-file

Comment: yeah, i know most of the scripting with wmi is done on PowerShell, I need to know if that json serialization is possible in python...

Answer (score 0):

Since i just ran into this myself:

`product` is a **_wmi_object** containing all kind of methods, classes and properties.

The actual data is in the property `properties` (which already is a `dict()`)

So something like:

```
json.dumps(product.properties)
```

Cheers